# OptimisticLockException within one transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, integration

Is it possible to get a OptimisticLockException exception within a transaction?

The enviroment is spring integration, jms inbound adapter, transacted and some serviceActivator with a lot of db operations and one of them throw that exception **sometimes**!
The actgiveMq tried 6 times and goes to dlq.

But I can not find the concurent other thread because the entity version not increased and lastModTime is before > 2 hours ago...

We can not reproduce it in the test envirroment :-(

Comment: Think the problem could be if multiple serviceActivator operations ran simultaniously

Comment: I do not think so because I use direct channel and nothing that broke transaction for example delayer, executor channel etc. The thread name is same in the log. The service activators are in chain and it executes one after the other